# Upward-growing content in scrolling parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have a fixed-height div (=> black-bordered box) with dynamically growing content (=> text with red background). The content needs to be positioned at the bottom of the div and growing upwards. If the content is taller than the black box, the black box must scroll.

I have tried the following, but it breaks the scrolling..

[image]

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  
  border: 1px solid black;  
}


p {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  color: black;
}

body { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div>
    
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      
</div>

<div>
    
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a javascript function to scroll your div to the bottom.

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*remove justify-content: flex-end;*/
  border: 1px solid black;  
}


p {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  color: black;
}

body { display: flex; }
```

```html
<div>
    
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      
</div>

<div id="div1">
    
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, Javascript scrolling is kind of broken by iOS momentum scrolling unfortunately, so thats not an option (I'm dynamically adding content)